# Prove $\{(2,0)\}$ is not extendable to a basis for $\mathbb{Z}^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, abelian-groups

I want to show that not every independent set in a free module is extendable to a basis.

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and consider the $R$-module $M=R^2=\mathbb{Z}^2$. Then, $M$ is free of rank $2$ and $S=\{(2,0)\}$ is clearly $R$-independent, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a domain.

How can I prove that $S$ is not extendable to a basis for $M$?

Thanks.

Comment: By supposing the contrary. How many elements can a basis have?

Comment: A basis of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ has two elements.

Comment: Then go for it and let us know where you are stuck.

Comment: Suppose $S=\{(2,0),(r,s)\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Z}^2$. These two elements need to be independent, so $(r,s)\ne k\cdot (2,0), k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that for $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, we have $(0,0)=x(2,0)+y(r,s)=(2x+ry,sy)$. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a domain we'll need $s=0$ or $y=0$. If $s=0$, then $2x+ry=0,\forall y$, in particular $y=1: r=-2x$ (contradiction). So $y=0$ and this forces $x=0$. So independency is OK. I'm kind of stuck with showing that each element in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ can be generated by $(2,0)$ and $(r,s)$.

Comment: Try to write $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ as linear combinations of the supposed basis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: let $(r, s)$ be arbitrary integers. What does it take to express $(1, 0)$ as an integral combination of $(2, 0)$ and $(r, s)$?

Comment: $1=2a+rb$ and $0=sb$, $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$. I showed in the comments that $s\ne 0$, so that would imply that $b=0$, but then $1=2a$ - a contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 \\ a & b 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since its determinant is $2b$, the matrix is never invertible over $\mathbb Z$. Therefore, $\{ (2,0),(a,b) \}$ is never a basis for $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

In general, an integer vector is part of a basis iff its entries are coprime.